# where is the bug in my VBA code?

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote this script to request roster from different teams however the code is not working.. need help to check where I am wrong.

```
Sub RosterRequest()
Dim counter As Integer
Dim outapp As Object
Dim outmail As Object

Set outapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set outmail = outapp.CreateItem(0)

Do While counter < 5
counter = counter + 1
c = Cells(counter, 1).Value
d = Cells(counter, 2).Value

    MsgBox ("loop number " & counter & " Name is " & c & " Email is " & d)
    With outmail
        .to = d
        .Subject = "Roster Request"
        .Body = "Hi " & c & " Please Share the roster for your team "
        .send
    End With

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: There may be other issues with this code, but one is that you only create one email, and then attempt to send it multiple times.

Comment: Thanx for ur help Steve. I want the do while loop to create the mail multiple times but its not doing that..

Comment: @NaveenSingh Instead of describing what the code is **not** doing, please describe what you see the code **is** doing, and how that differs from what you expect or would like to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the createItem(0) instruction in the do while loop like this

```
Do While counter < 5
 Set outmail = outapp.CreateItem(0)
counter = counter + 1
c = Cells(counter, 1).Value
d = Cells(counter, 2).Value

    MsgBox ("loop number " & counter & " Name is " & c & " Email is " & d)
    With outmail
        .to = d
        .Subject = "Roster Request"
        .Body = "Hi " & c & " Please Share the roster for your team "
        .send
    End With

Loop
```

Comment: Perfect..  Thanx for your helo h2so4.. the script worked and now i know where i was worng..

Comment: Could you then validate the answer ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have included the Microsoft Outlook 12.0 Object Library

In VBA Editor > goto Tools > References > and select the Microsoft Outlook 12.0 Object Library

2. Instead of using c = Cells(counter, 1).Value and d = Cells(counter, 2).Value, Try:

a.  c = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Shee1").Cells(counter, 1).Value

b.  d = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Shee1").Cells(counter, 2).Value

3. Also try counter = 0 before the Do While Loop:

counter = 0

Do While counter < 5

…..

4. Check if Outlook is configured.

a.  You are logged in.

b.  To send a mail via code, Outlook demands an antivirus, check if u got one.

i.  To check goto File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Programmatic Access AND look for Antivirus Status

Comment: The OP's code will not fail because the Outlook library is not referenced; the OP is using `CreateObject` to create a new `Outlook.Application`.